# How to Create a C Library from a jar File?

Tags: java, c, jar

I have a jar file of a library the contents of which are a bunch of *.class* files

```
spl
├── acm
│   ├── graphics
│   │   ├── DrawLineElement.class
│   │   ├── EndRegionElement.class
│   │   ├── FinalPathElement.class
│   │   ├── G3DRect.class
│   │   ├── GArc.class
│   │   ├── GCanvas.class
│   │   ├── GCanvasListener.class
│   │   ├── GCompound.class
│   │   ├── GContainer.class
│   │   ├── GDimension.class
│   │   ├── GFillable.class
│   │   ├── GImage.class
│   │   ├── GIterator.class
│   │   ├── GLabel.class
│   │   ├── GLine.class
│   │   ├── GMath.class
│   │   ├── GMouseEvent.class
│   │   ├── GObject.class
│   │   ├── GObjectList.class
│   │   ├── GOval.class
│   │   ├── GPen.class
│   │   ├── GPoint.class
│   │   ├── GPolygon.class
│   │   ├── GRectangle.class
│   │   ├── GRect.class
│   │   ├── GResizable.class
│   │   ├── GRoundRect.class
│   │   ├── GScalable.class
│   │   ├── GTurtle.class
│   │   ├── PathElement.class
│   │   ├── PathList.class
│   │   ├── PathState.class
│   │   ├── PenImage.class
│   │   ├── SetColorElement.class
│   │   ├── SetLocationElement.class
│   │   ├── StartRegionElement.class
│   │   └── VertexList.class
│   ├── gui
│   │   ├── DoubleField.class
│   │   ├── HPanel.class
│   │   ├── IntField.class
│   │   ├── TableConstraints.class
│   │   ├── TableLayout.class
│   │   ├── TablePanel.class
│   │   └── VPanel.class
│   ├── io
│   │   ├── AWTBooleanInputDialog.class
│   │   ├── AWTDialog.class
│   │   ├── AWTDialogModel.class
│   │   ├── AWTIconCanvas.class
│   │   ├── AWTLineInputDialog.class
│   │   ├── AWTMessageCanvas.class
│   │   ├── AWTMessageDialog.class
│   │   ├── CharacterQueue.class
│   │   ├── ConsoleActionListener.class
│   │   ├── ConsoleInputMonitor.class
│   │   ├── ConsoleModel.class
│   │   ├── ConsoleOutputMonitor.class
│   │   ├── ConsoleReader.class
│   │   ├── ConsoleWriter.class
│   │   ├── DialogModel.class
│   │   ├── IOConsole.class
│   │   ├── IODialog.class
│   │   ├── IOModel.class
│   │   ├── StandardConsoleModel.class
│   │   ├── SwingDialogModel.class
│   │   ├── SystemConsole.class
│   │   └── SystemConsoleModel.class
│   ├── program
│   │   ├── AppletStarter.class
│   │   ├── CommandLineProgram.class
│   │   ├── CommandLineProgramLoader.class
│   │   ├── ConsoleProgram.class
│   │   ├── DefaultActionListener.class
│   │   ├── DialogProgram.class
│   │   ├── GObjectProgram.class
│   │   ├── GProgramListener.class
│   │   ├── GraphicsProgram.class
│   │   ├── OldStyleCheckBoxMenuItem.class
│   │   ├── OldStyleMenuItem.class
│   │   ├── ProgramActionListener.class
│   │   ├── ProgramAppletStub.class
│   │   ├── Program.class
│   │   ├── ProgramContentPaneLayout.class
│   │   ├── ProgramFrame.class
│   │   ├── ProgramMenuBar.class
│   │   ├── ProgramMenuBarListener.class
│   │   ├── ProgramStartupListener.class
│   │   └── ProgramWindowListener.class
│   └── util
│       ├── Animator.class
│       ├── Base64OutputStream.class
│       ├── BMPImageSaver.class
│       ├── CancelledException.class
│       ├── DirectGif89Frame.class
│       ├── DOSCommandLine.class
│       ├── EmptyContainer.class
│       ├── EPSImageSaver.class
│       ├── ErrorException.class
│       ├── ExportAppletDialog.class
│       ├── FileChooserFilter.class
│       ├── Gif89Encoder.class
│       ├── Gif89Frame.class
│       ├── GIF89ImageSaver.class
│       ├── Gif89Put.class
│       ├── GifColorTable.class
│       ├── GIFImageSaver.class
│       ├── GifPixelsEncoder.class
│       ├── HexByteOutputStream.class
│       ├── HexInputStream.class
│       ├── ImageSaver.class
│       ├── IndexGif89Frame.class
│       ├── JPEGImageSaver.class
│       ├── JPGImageSaver.class
│       ├── JTFTools.class
│       ├── MailStream.class
│       ├── MediaTools.class
│       ├── NullAudioClip.class
│       ├── NullOutputStream.class
│       ├── OptionTable.class
│       ├── PICImageSaver.class
│       ├── PICTImageSaver.class
│       ├── Platform.class
│       ├── PNGImageSaver.class
│       ├── ProgressBarDialog.class
│       ├── RandomGenerator.class
│       ├── ReverseColorMap.class
│       ├── ReverseColorMap$ColorRecord.class
│       ├── RTFImageSaver.class
│       ├── SecurityManagerThatFails.class
│       ├── SoundClip.class
│       ├── SoundPlayer.class
│       ├── SpeedBarListener.class
│       ├── SubmitOptions.class
│       ├── SunAudioClip.class
│       ├── SwingTimer.class
│       ├── ThreadedMenuAction.class
│       ├── TIFFImageSaver.class
│       ├── TIFImageSaver.class
│       └── TokenScanner.class
├── META-INF
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
└── stanford
    └── spl
        ├── File_openFileDialog.class
        ├── G3DRect_create.class
        ├── G3DRect_setRaised.class
        ├── GArc_create.class
        ├── GArc_setFrameRectangle.class
        ├── GArc_setStartAngle.class
        ├── GArc_setSweepAngle.class
        ├── GButton.class
        ├── GButton_create.class
        ├── GCheckBox.class
        ├── GCheckBox_create.class
        ├── GCheckBox_isSelected.class
        ├── GCheckBox_setSelected.class
        ├── GChooser_addItem.class
        ├── GChooser.class
        ├── GChooser_create.class
        ├── GChooser_getSelectedItem.class
        ├── GChooser_setSelectedItem.class
        ├── GCompound_add.class
        ├── GCompound_create.class
        ├── GEvent_getNextEvent.class
        ├── GEvent_waitForEvent.class
        ├── GImage_create.class
        ├── GInteractor.class
        ├── GInteractor_getSize.class
        ├── GInteractor_setActionCommand.class
        ├── GLabel_create.class
        ├── GLabel_getFontAscent.class
        ├── GLabel_getFontDescent.class
        ├── GLabel_getGLabelSize.class
        ├── GLabel_setFont.class
        ├── GLabel_setLabel.class
        ├── GLine_create.class
        ├── GLine_setEndPoint.class
        ├── GLine_setStartPoint.class
        ├── GObject_contains.class
        ├── GObject_delete.class
        ├── GObject_getBounds.class
        ├── GObject_remove.class
        ├── GObject_rotate.class
        ├── GObject_scale.class
        ├── GObject_sendBackward.class
        ├── GObject_sendForward.class
        ├── GObject_sendToBack.class
        ├── GObject_sendToFront.class
        ├── GObject_setColor.class
        ├── GObject_setFillColor.class
        ├── GObject_setFilled.class
        ├── GObject_setLineWidth.class
        ├── GObject_setLocation.class
        ├── GObject_setSize.class
        ├── GObject_setVisible.class
        ├── GOval_create.class
        ├── GPolygon_addVertex.class
        ├── GPolygon_create.class
        ├── GRect_create.class
        ├── GRoundRect_create.class
        ├── GSlider.class
        ├── GSlider_create.class
        ├── GSlider_getValue.class
        ├── GSlider_setValue.class
        ├── GTextField.class
        ├── GTextField_create.class
        ├── GTextField_getText.class
        ├── GTextField_setText.class
        ├── GTimer.class
        ├── GTimer_create.class
        ├── GTimer_deleteTimer.class
        ├── GTimer_pause.class
        ├── GTimer_startTimer.class
        ├── GTimer_stopTimer.class
        ├── GWindow_addToRegion.class
        ├── GWindow_clear.class
        ├── GWindow_close.class
        ├── GWindow_create.class
        ├── GWindow_delete.class
        ├── GWindow_draw.class
        ├── GWindow_exitGraphics.class
        ├── GWindow_getScreenHeight.class
        ├── GWindow_getScreenWidth.class
        ├── GWindow_repaint.class
        ├── GWindow_requestFocus.class
        ├── GWindow_setRegionAlignment.class
        ├── GWindow_setResizable.class
        ├── GWindow_setTitle.class
        ├── GWindow_setVisible.class
        ├── JavaBackEnd.class
        ├── JBECanvas.class
        ├── JBECommand.class
        ├── JBEConsole.class
        ├── JBEConsole_clear.class
        ├── JBEConsole_getLine.class
        ├── JBEConsole_print.class
        ├── JBEConsole_println.class
        ├── JBEConsole_setFont.class
        ├── JBEConsole_setSize.class
        ├── JBEFileFilter.class
        ├── JBELabel.class
        ├── JBEWindow.class
        ├── Sound_create.class
        ├── Sound_delete.class
        ├── Sound_play.class
        ├── TopCompound.class
        └── TopCompound_create.class
```

Is it possible to create a C library from that jar file so that I can include, link and use it in my C applications? If yes, then how?

It's worth mentioning that I have access to all the header files of this library per the documentation [here](http://d2o9nyf4hwsci4.cloudfront.net/2013/fall/lectures/5/m/src5m/spl/doc/index.html).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for a pure C library, something that won't rely on a JVM, or just something you could call from a C code, but that would still start a JVM.

Comment: @dohashi the latter -- something that I could call from a C code, but would still start a JVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the Java Native Interface (JNI):

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/

You'll need to wrap the JNI calls into a C library interface that you build.

In particular, take a look at the invocation API that allows a C program to start a java JVM and execute java functions:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html

Comment: no, he isnt. JNI is for ACCESSING NATIVE LIBRARIES, not COMPILING THEM YOURSELVES

Comment: Check the comments.  Just want to access the java methods from a shared library.

Comment: well but regarding his comments in the question, it could help him anyway. But you have to make clear that JNI is about calling C from JAVA first and only **then** there are ways to call JAVA methods from C

Comment: actually starting the JVM yourself in C AND calling java-methods/functions is massive overkill and extremely error-prone - thats what the java-binary is for.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt JNI goes both ways.  You can call C from Java and Java from C.

Comment: I think this is the most correct answer up until now, but apparently using JNI will enable me to call Java functions from this library directly. I'm still not sure if this is the same way this library was used in a C application on another platform as there was a *.a* file that's being linked as this application was compiled and, as I mentioned, there are *.h* files that were included. However, the application still needed Java to be installed and started up exactly like a Java application with the Java icon. Any clues?

Comment: @Kareem What I'd suggest is writing your own C library that encapsulates the JNI stuff and allows you to call C functions in your applications.  These C functions would be mapped, via your C wrapper, into the corresponding Java method calls.  You might even want to add some java code to make the interface easier to access from C.  I will say that this may not be the easiest way to do it, it will give you exactly what you asked for.

Comment: .a files are native, static libraries - written in either C or C++. .h - files are C header-files. Unless there is ANY java-specific file involved anywhere the application is not calling java-code. One single exception, though : embedded resources, one is able to embed arbitrary files into the machine-code ... thats highly error-prone but it works. If you ever encounter such an application you'd be advised to avoid it, these are most likely malware or worse.

Comment: @specializt actually, it's an assignment for a course. They let us use this library on a specific platform in our application, but I want to get my application compiled on another platform.

Comment: if you get assignments with machine-code-embedded java-files ... you should ask yourself if these teachers are qualified for their job. Apparently not.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an executable jar, you can execute this as an external process, for example using `system()` function:

```
system("java -jar MyJar.jar");
```

It executes the command `java -jar MyJar.jar` in the host environment and returns after the command has been completed.

The command which is being executed:

`java -jar MyJar.jar`

simply runs your jar file.

[Here](http://www.gidforums.com/t-3369.html) you can find more ways to execute external program in C.

As an alternative, @dohashi's answer is good, too - you can use JNI for this. It works in both ways. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22881/How-to-Call-Java-Functions-from-C-Using-JNI) is a simple example how to use JNI to call Java 
methods from C.

Comment: thats the only correct answer, please extend it somehow if that is possible, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I actually need. As per my question, I'm supposed to include header files and use some of the resources in them and link the library's binary file as I'm compiling my C application. I have a compiled version of this library, but for another platform. When I run the C application, on this platform, I obviously see Java involved as if I ran a Java application. So I assume I'm supposed to have a C library binary file somehow.

Comment: that ... doesnt make much sense - you're mixing up quite a few things here.